# Adding product to cart programatically in woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

I'm adding products via ajax using a function in functions.php that looks like this:

```
function es_add_to_cart()
{       
    global $woocommerce;

    $product_id = $_GET['product_id'];
    $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id );

    die ( /*returns updated shopping cart */ );
}
```

This works and the item gets added *but only if the cart already contains an item*, this leads me to believe that I need to check if there is already a cart and create a new cart if there isn't. I can't find anything on this in the docs however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution to this problem, running `$woocommerce->cart->maybe_set_cart_cookies();` after adding any items, so the same function looks like this:

```
function es_add_to_cart()
{       
    global $woocommerce;

    $product_id = $_GET['product_id'];
    $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id );

    $woocommerce->cart->maybe_set_cart_cookies();

    die ( /*returns updated shopping cart */ );
}
```